# Error Provider in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, errorprovider

Is there any Error Provider for Windows Phone? 
For sure there is in .NET Framework 4.5 but I couldn’t have found for WP. 
That is a pity because this is very important to make login page properly.

When I wrote Error Provider I had in mind something like editText.setError in Android.

Comment: What exactly is an "error provider" for you?

Comment: I have added an explanation.

Comment: Maybe a good start? http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/windows-phone-7-validation/

Comment: You can achieve it by using the MVVM pattern